# How to check that the email message was successfully delivered in Bash?

Tags: bash, email

```
email_process=`echo -e "$BODY" | email -html -timeout 20 -V -s "$HEADER" "$USER_ADDRESS"`
if [[ "$email_process" == *"Sending"*"100% of"* ]]; then
    echo "   > successfully delivered";
fi
```

I try this. But this code does not work. Because `email_process=Connecting to server smtp.gmail.com on port 587`
The variable `email_process` must be equal

```
Connecting to server smtp.gmail.com on port 587
Sending  "test_text"  |********| 100% of 366 Bytes
Sending QUIT...
```

Comment: Can you post the result of `echo $?` after running the `email_process` if email succeeded and when it failed?

Comment: Pedantically, you can't verify the email was _delivered_, you can only check if it was **sent** successfully.

Comment: yes, I want to check if it was sent successfully

Comment: result of echo `$?` after running the `email_process` always are 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
wget -q --spider http://google.com
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Online"
else
    echo "Offline"
fi
```

I try this before email sending.